# Can I display validation errors above of an embedded form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Unfortunately I'm stuck with my comment functionality. The `comment` model has a polymorphic association with it's `commentables`. Here a sketch of the model: 
[image: model sketch]

Furthermore I have a `publications` controller, which displays of course some content, the comments and there is an embedded comment form. Another sketch about that:

[image: conteroller-view sketch]

1. Showing the publication, with it's comment form.
2. The comment form got submit and the data sent to the `create` action of the `comment` controller.
3. Unfortunately the data **failed** the validation.

My question is now, how I can I show the validation errors above my embedded form? I know I could use the `flash` to show an error, but then the user loses the form data.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.commentable = find_commentable

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to polymorphic_url(@comment.commentable, anchor: 'comment-' + @comment.id.to_s)
  else
    # What do I need to do here?
  end
end
```

How can I make the `@comment` available in `publications#show`?

I'm on Rails 4.1.

Comment: How does your publications/show view (and actually other commentables' show views) look like? I'm interested in the part that displays the "Comment form".

Comment: Here we go: https://gist.github.com/openscript/37c497bec47141d845dd

Comment: So, you already have `@comment` there in the `comments/form` partial and even do `@comment.errors.full_messages.each ...` inside it. How do you create `@comment` in the `PublicationsController` and other controllers for commentables? Looks like you need to pass @comment's attributes in url parameters to `redirect_to controller: @comment.commentable, action: :show` in case of error, and pick it up from the params[] there.

Comment: I'm sorry, in the gist is a newer version. I've added a :new view to the `comments_controller` and render that on validation error. Unfortunately it's still not the perfect solution, because the user don't see the publication above. It's not the embedded form anymore.

Comment: Btw, did you consider creating comments in your form using a special new action `PublicationsController#add_comment` rather than `CommentsController#create`? It'd take some rewriting but may help to get your ideal solution. You can create a module that you'd include in all your commentables to add that action to avoid repeating the code several times.

Comment: Probably that would be the perfect solution. Would you mind to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to work around the problem is to create a special action for creating comments in `PublicationsController` and other commentable controllers (you may want to create a module that you will include in all commentable controllers to avoid repetition and DRY the code).

I didn't have time to check on a test Rails app, so I may have made some typos or other errors, or forget about something in the code above. Still, I hope, the idea is clear. Feel free to edit if you find a bug.

In your `PublicationsController` (and other commentable controllers):

```
def add_comment
  # PublicationsController -> Publication
  @commentable_class = self.class.to_s[0..-11].singularize.constantize
  @commentable = @commentable_class.find(params[:commentable_id]) # it is passed by the form, see below
  # set @publication for the publication-specific part of the show view
  instance_variable_set('@'+@comentable_class.to_s.underscore, @commentable) 

  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params.merge(commentable: @commentable)) 

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to action: :show, anchor: 'comment-' + @comment.id.to_s
  else
    render action: :show
  end
end

...

def comment_params
  # don't forget to define comment_params - as in CommentsController, I guess:
  params.require(:comment).permit(:author,:subject,:message)
end
```

In the `show` action of those commentable controllers just do

```
def show
  ...
  @commentable_class = self.class.to_s[0..-11].singularize.constantize
  @comment = Comment.new
  @commentable = instance_variable_get('@'+@comentable_class.to_s.underscore)
  ...
end
```

In the `show` view for the commentables use something like the following form for adding the new comments (based on the provided gist):

```
- if @comment.errors.any?
  %section.errors
    %p= t('errors.templates.body')
    %ul
      - @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        %li= message
= form_for @comment, url: {controller: @commentable_controller, action: :add_comment} do |form|
  = hidden_field_tag 'commentable_id', @commentable.id
  - unless user_signed_in?
    .row
      .small-12.columns
        = form.label :author
        = form.text_field :author, required: true, pattern: '.{3,30}', title: t('errors.messages.not_in_between', from: 3, to: 30)
  .row
    .small-12.columns
      = form.label :subject
      = form.text_field :subject, pattern: '.{5,80}', title: t('errors.messages.not_in_between', from: 5, to: 80)
  .row
    .small-12.columns
      = form.label :message
      = form.text_area :message, required: true, pattern: '.{30,5000}', title: t('errors.messages.not_in_between', from: 30, to: 5000)
  = form.submit class: 'small radius button right'
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to add the following code to your `show` action in your `PublicationsController`: `@comment = Comment.new` (or `@comment = @publication.comment.new` depending). Then add some sort of `<%= @comment.errors.full_messages %>`-type code to your `show.html.erb` for the `Publication`. Finally, the `else` in your `comments#create` action should be: `render 'publications/show'`.

This will display the errors and will allow your comment form to be `<%= form_for @comment ...etc %>` so it will show whatever was typed into the comment form that didn't validate.

Comment: So I need to add all of the show action logic to the create action?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to set the other variables you need at that time like `@publication = @comment.commentable` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is not the solution, because it's not always `publications/show` as `Comment` is polymorphic.

Comment: Okay, so you might need to change what you are rendering based on what the comment was on. The key lesson is that you must `render` from within the `create` action in order to display the comment information since it is not stored in the database and will be lost if you redirect.

Comment: Okay, yes I understand that. So that's the only way to do that? I have to patch together such a string?

Comment: If it is a very small amount of information you could store it in the session and then redirect_to a different controller that accesses the info from the session, but it really isn't designed for that and has a (I believe) 4k limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62846/discussion-between-robin-and-ptd).